# Custom Validation for a Plain Text Field

Tags: validation

I have a field created in **Field Settings** and I want to add some specific validations to this field.

None of the Field Types fit with what I want to validate.

Do you know a way to validate this field with my own rules?
[image]

Comment: Check out https://nystudio107.com/blog/extending-craft-cms-with-validation-rules-and-behaviors